# Need help defining ranges and strings with this Looping Split script

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of data in column C, and I'm looking to put the output from this split function into column D. The script I have written so far is:

```
 Sub SplitTest()
     Dim txt As String
     Dim Rng As Range
     Dim i As Integer
     Dim Authors As Variant
     i = 2
     Set Rng = Range("C" & i)
     txt = Rng.Value
     Authors = Split(txt, ["."])

    For i = 2 To UBound(Authors)
        Set Rng = Range("C" & i)
        Range("D" & i + 1).Value = Authors(i)
        Next i
    End Sub
```

Now, the script only runs for rows 3 to 5. Is there something wrong with the `Range("D"...` line?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have not devfined Rng. before you are trying to use it.  set range = Range("A1")

Comment: You are only looping the results of the split and not the rows.  See edits to answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set range before you can use it.

```
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Range("C" & i)
txt = Rng.Value
```

Also, you will need to set i = some row number before you can use it. You now have

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim Authors As Variant
Set Rng = Range("C" & i)
```

But i isn't set yet. You need to set it.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim Authors As Variant
i = 1
Set Rng = Range("C" & i)
```

EDIT: per OP comments.

Look at putting all that into a loop over the rows.

```
Sub SplitTest()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Dim txt As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Authors As Variant
    Dim strColumn As String

    Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet

    lRow = 1

    'Loop through process each row.
    Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.count

        Set Rng = Range("C" & lRow)

        txt = Rng.Value
        Authors = Split(txt, ["."])

        'Loop through the split results and put them in column to the right
        For i = 0 To UBound(Authors)
            strColumn = Col_Letter(i + 4)
            ws.Range(strColumn & lRow) = Authors(i)
        Next i

        lRow = lRow + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Add this function

```
Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
    Col_Letter = vArr(0)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question to include your suggestion, but now I'm getting a '_global' error for the Set Rng line.

Comment: "Method 'range' of object '_Global' failed," runtime error 1004.

Comment: See edit. I'm not sure what the bigger picture is for this code, Will the row to process be passed into the sub?

Comment: I want to do the equivalent of having a Split Formula in column D, and pulling down to process each string in the relative cell. So like having `=Split(C2, ".")' in D2`, and pulling it down through to D100 like a normal function.

Comment: So you want to loop row 1 - 100 splitting cell C and putting the first value in cell D? You only care about the first value or the split?

Comment: For now, I only care about the first value. Once I get the code working, I'll tweak it on my own.

Comment: The script is running now, but stopping prematurely. Please see the edit to my question if you'd like more context.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Nothing happens when I run that script. At what point does it select the Output to be in column D?

Comment: Something with the cells() = authors() is messed up.  Replace it with ws.Range("D" & lRow) = Authors(i)

Comment: Tracked it down. Just use range. See multiple edits above. Tested and working

Comment: Awesome. This is perfect. Thanks for your help and your patience!

Comment: Glad to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

In your case:

```
i = 2 '<--- Some integer value
Set Rng = Range("C" & i)
txt = Rng.Value
Authors = Split(txt, ["."])
```

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question to include your suggestion, but now I'm getting a '_global' error for the Set Rng line.

Comment: Because in your sub, value of `i` is empty. Assign some value to `i` and then run your code

Comment: Thanks for the help. The script is running now, but it's stopping prematurely. See the edit to the question if you want to know more.